# How can I Automate Google 2 step mobile verification in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-authentication

**Environment**

Azure websites

Dot.net framework

**Configuration**

Selenium 3.14

Google Version 96.0.4664.110

**Challenge**

Using selenium automate Google 2 step mobile verification while singing in to application.
Tried using below code but not working.

```
import org.jboss.aerogear.security.otp.Totp;

public class TOTPGenerator {
    /**
     * Method is used to get the TOTP based on the security token
     * @return
     */
    public static String getTwoFactorCode(){
//Replace with your security key copied from step 12
        Totp totp = new Totp("nlyyriaxspwdomi7buvo32cuas6tz7aa"); // 2FA secret key
        String twoFactorCode = totp.now(); //Generated 2FA code here
        return twoFactorCode;
    }
}
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TwoFactorGmail {

public static void gmailSignIn(){

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\\chromedriver.exe");
        
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
 driver.manage().window().maximize();

 driver.get("your application url which embeds gmail sign-in");

driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");

 driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
      
 driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
      
 driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
  
// OTP value is returned from getTwoFactor method
 driver.findElement(By.id("totpPin")).sendKeys(TOTPGenerator.getTwoFactorCode());
        
 driver.findElement(By.id("totpNext")).click();
    }
}
```